# Application Stop when input editText more than 10 digit

Tags: java, android

i am trying to show calculation textView(txtHasil) it is running but when input more than 10 application suddenly force close. this is my code:

```
btnHitung.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        //String plafond = NumberTextWatcherForThousand.trimCommaOfString(edtPlafond.getText().toString());
        String plafond = edtPlafond.getText().toString().trim();
        String jasa = edtJasa.getText().toString().trim();

        int edtPlafond = Integer.parseInt(plafond);
        float edtJasa = Float.parseFloat(jasa);

        double hasil = (edtPlafond * edtJasa )/100;


        txtHasil.setText(""+hasil+"\nplafond: "+edtPlafond+"\nJasa: "+edtJasa);
        //txtHasil.addTextChangedListener(new NumberTextWatcherForThousand((EditText) txtHasil));
    }
}
```

i have been try change int,float, and double. i have been read this link: [This program doesn't work properly for decimals more than 10 digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28352242/this-program-doesnt-work-properly-for-decimals-more-than-10-digits) but didn't help. any suggest will be help. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Integer.parseInt(plafond);
```

This is the problem.It can not parse anythong larger than [Integer.MAX_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)

```
int edtPlafond;
try {

    edtPlafond = Integer.parseInt(plafond);

} catch (NumberFormatException e ) {
   e.printStackTrace(); 
   // add proper error handling
}
```

The best would be to have a longer value - long...

```
long edtPlafond;
try {

    edtPlafond = Long.parseLong(plafond);

} catch (NumberFormatException e ) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   // add proper error handling
}
```

And an example of handling the error in a better way, by displaying the error in a dialog:

```
} catch (NumberFormatException e ) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
          .setTitle("Error: incorrect number entered!")
          .setMessage("The exact error is: " + e.getMessage())
          .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int b) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
          .create()
          .show();
}
```

**Note**: all conversions need such a treatment...

Comment: thanks, that's better than force stop. but need a little revision in catch:
use ( not {

Comment: Sorry, was typing from a phone, didn't see the difference between the two brackets... Also, added another snippet, with long type, that should be able to hold longer values...

Comment: Was that meant jokingly? For someone who doesn't understand data types to tell someone helping them, that they don't know how to write error handling... My mind is blown

Comment: @NickCardoso hmmm, you're right... I'll correct this but takes a while on a phone...

Comment: @ppeterka I think you've misunderstood me. I was shocked by 'Steven's comment implying you didn't understand it. That's why I asked if it was meant jokingly

Comment: @NickCardoso Ah I see (damn language barrier...) I understood Steve's comment to be a friendly remark about the syntax error I made in the answer. Well at least the answer got better and more useful for future SO dwellers.